# Django Apps aren't loaded yet - can't import model

Tags: django, django-celery

I can't import my model into my celery.py file so I use it in a scheduled task - I always get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

I'm tearing my hair out - a few people seem to have got the same error, but none in the same circumstances and I tried all the fixes and nothing works.

My celery.py file in my main Django app:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import requests
import os
from celery import Celery

from WeatherData.models import LondonWeather

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Weather.settings')
from .settings import OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY, OPEN_WEATHER_API_URL
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.


app = Celery('Weather')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Gets London weather every hour.

    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, get_weather_task.s(), name='london_weather_test')
    sender.add_periodic_task(3600.0, get_weather_task.s(), name='london_weather')


@app.task()
def get_weather_task():

    querystring = {"q": "London,UK"}

    headers = {
        'x-api-key': OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY,
    }

    res = requests.get(OPEN_WEATHER_API_URL, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

    LondonWeather.objects.create(
            longitude=res.get('coord', 0).get('lon', 0),
            latitude=res.get('coord', 0).get('lat', 0),
            main_weather=res.get('weather', {})[0].get('main', 'Rain'),
            description=res.get('weather', {})[0].get('description', 'No data'),
            temperature=res.get('main', {}).get('temp', 0),
            pressure=res.get('main', {}).get('pressure', 0),
            humidity=res.get('main', {}).get('humidity', 0),
            min_temp=res.get('main', {}).get('temp_min', 0),
            max_temp=res.get('main', {}).get('temp_max', 0),
            wind_speed=res.get('wind', {}).get('speed', 0),
            wind_direction=res.get('wind', {}).get('deg', 0),
            clouds=res.get('clouds', {}).get('all', 0),
    )

    return res
```

The **init**.py of my main app looks like this because of clery:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Is this messing with Django's imports?

Comment: i don't know all details, but looks like simple solution is do `from WeatherData.models import LondonWeather` inside your function `get_weather_task`

Comment: That works! Why does that make any difference tho?

Comment: you get python recursive import when initial your app.